# How does $\lim A_n$ being not invertible imply $\sup_n\|A_n^{-1}\|=\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

> Consider a sequence of operators $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset B(X,Y)$, where $X,Y$ are normed vector spaces and $B(X,Y)$ denotes the space of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$. Assume that all $A_n$ are invertible (i.e., 1-1 and onto) and
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty} A_n=A\ \ \text{in operator norm}
> $$
>   where $A:X\to Y$ is not invertible. Show that
>   $$
> \sup_n \|A_n^{-1}\|=\infty
> $$

If $\sup_n\|A_n^{-1}\|=M<\infty$ for some $M\in{\Bbb R}$, then I'm trying to show that $A$ must be invertible. What I've done is showing that $A$ is 1-1:

Since $\|A_n-A\|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, we have
$$
\|A_nx-Ax\|\leq\|A_n-A\|\|x\|\to 0\ \ \text{as}\  n\to\infty
$$
for all $x\in X$. Hence, if $Ax=0$ then $\|A_nx\|\to 0$, i.e., for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N>0$ such that
$$
\|A_nx\|\leq \varepsilon/M
$$
for all $n>N$. (One can show that $M>0$, so we have no problem with $1/M$). It follows that
$$
\|x\|=\|A_n^{-1}(A_nx)\|\leq \|A_n^{-1}\|\|A_nx\|\leq M\cdot \varepsilon/M=\epsilon.
$$
Thus $x=0$.

How can I show that $A$ is also onto?

---

[ADDED:]I suspect that one might need the assumption of completeness of $X$ and $Y$. But I don't see a quick counterexample when one of $X$ and $Y$ is not Banach space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have to consider the problem over the completion $\overline X$ of $X$. But that does not hurt our reasoning: if $A$ is not invertible, neither will its extension to $\overline X$ be.

Assuming that $\|A_n^{-1}\|\leq M$ for all $n$, we have
$$
\|A_n^{-1}-A_m^{-1}\|=\|A_n^{-1}(A_m-A_n)A_m^{-1}\|\leq\,M^2\,\|A_m-A_n\|.
$$
As $\{A_n\}$ is Cauchy, we deduce that so is $\{A_n^{-1}\}$.

Let $A'=\lim A_n^{-1}$. Then
$$
AA'=\lim_n A_nA_n^{-1}=I,\ \ A'A=\lim_nA_n^{-1}A_n=I,
$$
so $A$ is invertible. Note that we are using that the norm limit is multiplicative.

Comment: @Martin, Thank you for your answer. For the existence of $A'$, do you need the completeness of $X$ (which would imply that $B(Y,X)$ is a Banach space)?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point, Jack. We need $X$ to be Banach to talk about the inverse. But we can work on the completion. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Thank you for your editing. Could you elaborate why "When $A:X\to Y$ is not invertible, then its extension to $\overline{X}$ is not invertible either"?

Comment: Say $X\subset Z$ and $A:Z\to Y$ invertible; so there exists $B$ with $BA=I_Z$, $AB=I_Y$. Then $A\mid_X$ is also invertible with inverse $B\mid_{\mbox{im}(A)}; indeed, for any $x\in X$, $BAx=x$, as $x\in Z$. And for any $Ax$, $ABAx=Ax$.